# Sublime Text Less2Css Disable Auto Calculation

Tags: css, less, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text with Less2Css to Css- and minify my less files. I want to set the max-height of a container to 100% - 20px like so:

```
max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

Unfortunately the Less2Css minifies '100% - 20px' to '80%'. Are there any workarounds? Can I somehow tell Less2Css not to minify anything surrounded by special characters (e.g. ****max-height: calc(100% - 20px);****)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in a string and the escape it.

This, in Less:

```
.section {
    max-width: ~'calc(100% - 20px)';
}
```

will generate this CSS:

```
.section {
  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```